# google sign in works on emulator but not in release mode on android device flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-signin

I am building an app in flutter (in vs code) that involves google sign in with firebase. The sign in works on an emulator but not on release (closed testing on google play). The error I am getting is "Flutter and google_sign_in plugin: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)".
I have tried everything I could think of following the links at the end of the post.

I added both SHA-1 and SHA-256 from App signing key certificate in google play console to project settings in firebase.
I redownloaded the google-sevices.json file and replaces it with my current one.
I ran flutter clean.
I made sure my support mail was registered.
I defined my OAuth.
I rebuilt the appbundle and uploaded the new version.
Can anyone suggest anything I haven't done yet?
Thanks in advance!
I followed the following links:
[Google sign in working on emulator but not on Android device flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67948512/google-sign-in-working-on-emulator-but-not-on-android-device-flutter)

[Google login works in emulator but not in phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029310/google-login-works-in-emulator-but-not-in-phone)

[Flutter and google_sign_in plugin: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557479/flutter-and-google-sign-in-plugin-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it. This was very weird, I had two android apps registered on firebase and it wouldnt let me add the SHA keys to both. Once I deleted the unnecessary app it let me add the SHA keys.